# Filter on the day of the week from timestamp

Tags: filters, admin, query, mysql, date

I'm trying to filter the display of posts by the day of the week (1=Mon, 2=Tues, etc) in the admin edit area. The custom field 'some-date' is a timestamp. The code below is *not* the right approach to this, but illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

```
// Filter on day of week
add_filter( 'parse_query', array( &$this, 'dayFilter' ), 10);

// Filter the query on the day of the week held by custom timestamp field 'some-date'
public function dayFilter( $query )
{
    // Essential code below

    $qv = &$query->query_vars;
    $qv['meta_query'] = [];

    // Filter on the day of week
    if ( !empty( $_GET['filter_day_of_Week'] ) )
    {
        $day = intval( $_GET['filter_day_of_Week'], 10 );
        $qv['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(wpcf-some-date))',
            'value' => $day,
            'compare' => 'IS'
        );
        $sort_key = 'wpcf-some-date';
    }
}
```

Not here, but somewhere I'm going to need to get `WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(wpcf-some-date))` into the request SQL. I've thought about hacking the SQL request string in the `posts_request` filter hook, but if anyone has a better suggestion I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I would consider storing it additionally as weekday, when you add the wpcf-some-date meta data.

Comment: Unfortunately that cannot be done. It would not account for timezone differences. A more robust solution is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may help someone who really wants to customize their filters. With PhpStorm and breakpoints I could walk through how the `meta_query` is constructed before posts are fetched. There are no hook points in the flow that let developers accomplish this; I've used a SQL-injection trick to achieve the filter.

```
// Do advanced SQL editing for filtering the days of the week
add_filter( 'posts_where_request', array( &$this, 'processSQLDelMarkers' ), 99, 2 );

/**
 * Manipulate the pre-flight SQL query to filter on the day of the week.
 * Remove any ##DEL## marker as well as the next character after it
 * @param $where
 * @return mixed
 */
public function processSQLDelMarkers($where, \WP_Query &$query)
{
    // Special gate
    if (stripos($where, '##DEL##') === false) {
        return $where;
    }

    // ... security checks omitted for brevity ...

    /**
     *  Sample where clause before adjustment:
     *  ... AND ihs_postmeta.meta_value != '##DEL##\' AND WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ihs_postmeta.meta_value)) = 4##DEL##' ) ...
     *  becomes
     *  ... AND ihs_postmeta.meta_value != '' AND WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ihs_postmeta.meta_value)) = 4 ) ...
     */
    return preg_replace( '(##DEL##.?)', '', $where );
}
```

Then using a carefully constructed meta `value` and dummy `compare` like so (see the code in the original question) I could achieve the SQL injection:

```
$qv['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => '##DEL##\' AND WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ihs_postmeta.meta_value)) = 4##DEL##',
    'value' => $day,
    'compare' => '!='
);
```

**Note**: With the right security checks it should not be possible to inject unwanted SQL strings.

Comment: Since no other answers have surfaced, and this works, I shall accept it.